# Java - Preventing Java Heap memory error using Swing framework and abstract classes

Tags: java, swing, memory-management

Really hope you can assist. I have built a stock management application with the Java Swing framework. This application has 1 abstract class named GUIRules which extends JPanel implements actionListener, and 8 different classes which extend GUIRules to represent each screen.

```
public abstract class GUIRules extends JPanel implements ActionListener{}

public class login extends GUIRules {}
```

The fact is all of these 8 classes have a lot in common; hence the reason I decided to provide each one of them with default functionality.

When I navigate to each screen, all loads up fine; however, I eventually encounter Java Heap memory error. This is the method which enables the changing of screen:

```
    /**
 * When switching between GUI screens, declare new GUI within parameters
 * @param panel 
 */
public void changePanel(JPanel panel){
    this.removeAll();   
    this.add(panel); 
    validate();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

this.removeAll() is supposed to remove all components, thereby freeing memory. All action listeners are added within the constructors of all the 8 screens; so this should also get disposed of when this function is called.

This application also utilises images as well.

The abstract class (GUIrules) calls paintComponent() to load the background image:

```
    /**
 * Paint background, menu and logo images onto this class.
 */
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image.mainImg, 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
    g.drawImage(image.menuImg, 0, 30, getWidth(), 80, null); 
    g.drawImage(image.logoImg, 0, 33, null); g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.drawString(SystemSession.user, 10, 20);
    g.drawString(SystemSession.status, 10, getHeight()-10);
    repaint();
}
```

I have used Runtime.gc() to garbage collect unused objects but not much difference. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Should this be tagged [jsr-296](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsr296/info)?

Comment: Upvoted cus I think I know you...... Timer?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer** - increase your maximum Heap Size [using the `-Xmx` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#options).

The maximum heap size available to the Java VM can be increased.  The default value depends on your system but you can increase this, bearing in mind on the memory available on the system where you're running your application.  For example, to increase the maximum heap size to 1GB use something like:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar yourapp.jar
```

**Longer answer** - use a profile to see if you can reduce the memory usage of your application.

[There are tools which will allow you to examine the memory usage of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler) is it runs.  This will enable you to see if objects are being garbage collected as you expect or if you have a memory leak which is causing you to run out of heap space.

Comment: I tried out "YourKit" Java profiler; however it is very complicated to use. I need a profiler that will simply tell me how much memory in perhaps Megabytes, each method or component is using of the memory. Any easy to use profilers you know of?

Comment: Are you using a Java IDE? That may have a profiler built in which is probably the best place to start. Otherwise look at the question about profilers I have linked to in my answer.

Comment: Well, have you tried the Eclipse Profiler?  http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nav/40

Comment: Hi Dave, just a quick question about the cmd statement you provided to increase Java heap memory. How would you alter this statement to use a JAR file on my desktop? At current, I believe I would need to relocate my JAR file in the Java directory. Regards awb

Comment: @AWb - Just use something like `java -Xmx1024M -jar C:\path\to\your\desktop\yourapp.jar`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are placing remove all on the EDT or else your application will experience issues as you encounter.

```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            this.removeAll();   
            this.add(panel); 
            validate();
            setVisible(true);
        }
   });
```

Comment: My application starts up on the EDT. Does this not have any effect on the program?

Comment: This looks like the answer, try it.

Comment: Hi AWb, it applies to any calls not getting processed by the 'actionPerformed' or listener events from user interaction. If you're using runnable tasks in or from other threads, you definitely need to place this on the EDT. If you're unsure, you can always try it out.

Comment: Hi Jason, in my ActionPerformed method on my login page, I utilise a thread which authenticates the user. I presume the EDT should be used in this?

Comment: Hi AWb, you have to be extremely careful what you place on the EDT, via invokeLater. Synchronous calls, specifically service, wait/sleep, and network calls, can block and freeze the UI. You only want to place the swing related methods on the EDT, like setText, add, validate, removeAll, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It is clear you have a memory leak. Although it is not shown in your code, I assume the leak is caused by your listeners based on

> this.removeAll() is supposed to remove all components, thereby freeing memory. All action listeners are added within the constructors of all the 8 screens; so this should also get disposed of when this function is called.

When an instance of class `A` is a listener which is attached to instance `B`, instance `B` will keep a strong reference to the listener, hence a strong reference to `A`. So removing your references to `A` and keeping a reference to `B` will make sure `A` is not GC-ed, as it is strongly referenced by `B`.

In your case, `A` is your `GUIRules` class and `B` whatever class you attach your `GUIListener` to. Calling `removeAll` on the container which is used to display your `GUIRules` does not allow to GC that instance when it is still attached as a listener to another object to which you keep a strong reference.

Beside that, have you considered using a `CardLayout` to switch between the 8 panels. This will keep the 8 panels in memory, but avoids the need to create new ones every time (which I assume you do now or you would not encounter the OoM exception)

Comment: Hi Robin, can you explain why the CardLayout manager would keep my 8 panels in memory? Surely, if I am using this.removeAll(), my panels and components have to reload each time anyway.

Comment: A CardLayout just keeps a 'list of components', but only shows one at a time. My guess for your memory leak is that you constantly re-create panels which are not GC-ed. With the CardLayout you can just switch between the panels (by using the show method and not the removeAll) and you never need to create new panels

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryError mean that you have memory leak in your code or you need to increase your heap memory size.

in case of memory leak, your code is not enough (to see what is the real problem) , anyway you should profile your application to fix the problem, see this article:
http://java.dzone.com/news/how-fix-memory-leaks-java

in case of your application need more memory just increase the heap size:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1g yourApplication
```